# Bind html Attribute doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net

first example works. second fails misrebly why?

```
(I except ErrorMessage="<%# Model.StringProvider.GetString("Login.UserNameRequired.ErrorMessage")%>")
```

to put the callled string in ErrorMessage this doesn't happen.

```
<asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName"><%= Model.StringProvider.GetString("Login.UserNameLabel")%></asp:Label>





<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                        ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="<%# Model.StringProvider.GetString("Login.UserNameRequired.ErrorMessage")%>"
                                        ToolTip='<%= Model.StringProvider.GetString("Login.UserNameRequired.ToolTip")%>.' ValidationGroup="Login1">

                                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

both '' and "" don't work

Comment: Explain *fails miserably* ...

Comment: means that when I run the code `<%# Model.StringProvider.GetString("Login.UserNameRequired.ErrorMessage")%>` is not called

Comment: maybe it lacks of escape character.